# Insert custom post data in to MailChimp campaign email

Tags: custom-post-types, api, plugin-mailchimp

I'm interested in injecting custom post type data in to MailChimp emails via their API. A simple undordered list of links to each post. After researching this and reading through MailChimp's documentation I cannot find a clearly defined means of doing via SOAP/REST.

Does anyone have experience with this and if so can you please add some clarity around this?

Comment: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/create.php - scroll down to the documentation on content struct, that parameter allows you send raw html which you can build to contain your list of posts.  This question doesn't deal specifically with WordPress and will likely be closed as off topic since the base question really is, "How do I insert arbitrary html into a mailchimp message?".  If you run into specific implementation problems about retrieving information in WordPress, please post here, otherwise I think mailchimp type questions are probably better on SO proper.

Comment: Fair enough and I do agree with this being closed off topic. Sorry for posting as such, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.